# Android: how to detect ACTION_DOWN on parent AND clicks on children?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, touch-event

I am subclassing a `ListView`:

- if I define an `OnClickListener` on a view of the listview's item, the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` on the listview doesn't get triggered anymore
- If I remove the listener, the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` gets triggered no problem.

It seems like the ACTION_DOWN is "stolen" by the child view.

**My question is:**

How can I achieve both these things?

- detect the ACTION_DOWN on the listview
- detect clicks on views on a list item

**HERE SOME CODE:**

I am overriding the `onTouchEvent` on a `ListView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ...
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

And I am also defining a click listener on the item

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        ...
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_routesresults, null);
        ...
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    ...
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    });
    ....

    return rowView;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just verified that if I define the click on the item using `setOnItemClickListener` on the listview instead of defining `setOnItemClickListener` directly on the item view, `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` on the listview gets triggered:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Can someone explain why defining the click directly on the view, prevents the ACTION_DOWN to trigger on the listview?